# override templateurl for component in angularjs1.5

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-1.5

I want to override the templateurl of the component.

Lets say I have below component.

```
angular.
module('myApp').
component('greetUser', {
template: usertemplate.html,
controller: function GreetUserController() {
this.user = 'world';
}
});
```

I am want to override this component so that whenever they access geet-user my custom template.html.
It tired by re declaring the same but it is throwing an error saying two selector for geet-user.
Any suggestions?

Thanks,In Advance.
Sree.

Comment: You can either go with creating a new component itself with your new template. Is there any limitation ?

Comment: Yes.The component is in 3rd party library.

Comment: May be http://thaiat.github.io/blog/2014/03/10/extending-an-existing-directive-in-angularjs/ can help.. And may I know the 3rd party library name ?

Comment: It is related hybris commerce smartedit library

Comment: @RajatMishra Thanks. That document is mainly about the controller.Mine is to override the template.